# Como calcular hash?

Tags: php, hash, bittorrent, torrent

Como faço para calcular a *hash* de um arquivo torrent com PHP?

Já utilizei a classe `BEncoded` e funcionou, porém queria saber como funciona.

Comment: Você fala de um hash do arquivo inteiro? Ou é o hash das peças, tal como exigido na [sua estrutura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#File_structure)? (caso em que o correto a ser usado seria o SHA-1) Por que você quer calcular esse hash, que uso você tem pra ele?

Comment: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:`640FE84C613C17F663551D218689A64E8AEBEABE`.
Queria saber como faço para descobrir esse btih.

Se não me engano, tenho q descobrir o hash dos pedaços, mas não sei como.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um arquivo torrent possui uma estrutura de dados com duas chaves de nível mais alto: `announce` - identificando o(s) *tracker(s)* a serem utilizados para download - e `info` - contendo os nomes dos arquivos e os hashes relevantes (das peças, creio eu, mas não tenho certeza). Para se criar links "magnet", usa-se o `infohash` que é justamente um hash dos dados codificados do `info`. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22240583/520779).

Ou seja, para se calcular esse `infohash` é necessário abrir o arquivo torrent, interpretar sua estrutura e calcular o hash da parte relevante (pelo que entendi do citado acima, não e preciso *decodificar* a estrutura toda, mas ainda é necessário *selecioná-la* dentro do arquivo).

O detalhe é que, como o `infohash` é um hash da estrutura **codificada**, e o `BencodeModel` decodifica tudo, acaba sendo necessário codificar novamente a parte relevante, antes de aplicar o hash:

- Decodifica e pega a parte relevante (`info`):

  ```
  $bencode = new BencodeModel();
  $data = $bencode->decode_file($form->fields['filename']->saved_file);
  $hash = $torrentmanager->create_hash($data['info']);
  ```
- Re-codifica e calcula o hash:

  ```
  function create_hash($info)
  {
      $bencode = new BencodeModel();
      return urlencode(sha1($bencode->encode($info)));
  }
  ```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6527357/520779).

Comment: Vou estudar essa classe.
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias formas dependendo do propósito.

Uma das mais comuns é usar MD5. Isto é feito com a função [`md5_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php).

Também pode usar a [`sha1_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php) que é mais lenta mas um dá um resultado um pouco melhor.

Comment: De fato, essa é a forma correta de se calcular o hash de um arquivo inteiro, mas no caso do *magnet link* somente uma parte do arquivo torrent precisa ser hasheada (a parte constante, que descreve o conteúdo; a parte que descreve os *trackers* pelo meu entendimento pode mudar, de modo que um hash dela não tem muita utilidade).

Comment: Com as informações adicionais parece ser, eu só respondi o que a pergunta falava.